# Optional decodable array that should filter failing items

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, codable

Say I have this struct:

```swift
struct Book: Codable {

   let id: Int
   let title: String
   let authorName: String
}
```

and this struct holds an instance to it:

```swift
struct BookShop: Codable {

   let name: String
   let books: [Book]
}
```

And say, in my API, two things could happen:

1. There is no `books` node for some shops
2. Some `Book` objects that come down in the response are malformed (when they shouldn't be).

So, for example:

Scenario 1:

```json
{
   "store": {
      "name": "Waterstones"
      // Missing books array
   }
}
```

or Scenario 2 - there is a bug in the API and it returns the following:

```json
{
   "store": {
      "name": "Waterstones",
      "books": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Harry Potter"
            // Missing author name
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Scenario 1 is a valid scenario and should be handled by the app, and I guess you'd do that by updating `BookShop` to:

```swift
struct BookShop: Codable {

   let name: String
   let books: [Book]? <--- Make this optional.
}
```

However, in Scenario 2, I don't *want* to make `authorName` optional, I just want books without it to be filtered at decode time.

For this, I found this article: http://marksands.github.io/2019/10/21/better-codable-through-property-wrappers.html

That has a property wrapper called `LossyArray` that will try to decode each item in turn and just skip it if it fails.

So that brings my `BookShop` struct up to this:

```swift
struct BookShop: Codable {

   let name: String
   @LossyArray let books: [Book]?
}
```

But it doesn't work! In Scenario 1, I get this error:

```
No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "books", intValue: nil)
```

Is it possible to achieve these things at the same time? Or do I *have* to make all the items in `Book` optional/let the whole home page fail to decode if one item is incorrect?

**UPDATE**: I just found that this works:

```swift
struct BookShop: Codable {

   let name: String
   let books: LossyArray<Book>?
}
```

I guess it's weird that I can't represent this as a property wrapper.

Comment: if you are uncertain of what data you receive, did you try to manually decode each key? you can use decodeIfPresent for authorName, and assign a empty string if decode fails.

Comment: Yeah I'm happy to do that, I'd just hoped there was a way to make it generic since this could happen across multiple models.